# Formik doesn't reinitialize when initial value is null

Tags: formik

I'm building an app with React and using Formik to handle the forms.

When I'm working on Update function, null fields keep the value of the previous record where they were not null.

For example:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Green"
},
{
    "firstName": "Angela",
    "lastName": null
},
{
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Blue"
}
```

When I open John, and then Angela, her last name is still shown as Green.
If I go back to index page and open Angela again, it shows correctly.

I have already added `enableReinitialize: true`.

Is there a proper way to handle null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a null coalesce operator to pass an empty string instead of  null.

```
value={values.nullProperty ?? ""}
```